# How to disable change of date field value in webform

Tags: webforms

I have created a webform using [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module. I have used field *date*, which I use as access date. I want user not to edit this date. Then what do I need to do?
I have tried *min date* and *max date* as today in field setting. But, I want user not to be able to select also.
Any one has an idea to disable date field or auto save today's date?

Comment: When a webform is submitted, webform writes a timestamp to the webform_submissions table. Would that be enough information for you?

Comment: Ok I will do it.